# Chartjs with Node.js : Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.js with node.js.
I downloaded Chart.js from the following git source: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js
and tested it with php and things worked fine.

Now I am working with node.js but I have an issue:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "url/Chart.js/Chart.js" localhost/:3 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     /Chart.js/Chart.js:1

**debug.html**

```
<html><head>
  <script src="Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
</head></html>
```

**index.js**

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

var fichier=fs.readFileSync('debug.html', 'utf-8');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    res.write(fichier);

    res.end();
});
server.listen(80);
```

I know that the path is good, node can find it so what is the problem?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What if you use a valid HTML page (with a doctype and everything) and write `type="text/javascript"` on the `script` tag

Comment: Hmm... Isn't it complaining about `Chart.js`, line #1?

Comment: Try to access `http://localhost/Chart.js/Chart.js`, you should see that your server always serves the same page for each request, without taking into account the path.

Comment: Paul you're rigth, I'm a novice with node.js and didn't thought about that.
I will handle the request url, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP server doesn't look at the requested URL and always sends back the same page:

```sh
$ curl http://localhost/
<html><head>
  <script src="Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
</head></html>

$ curl http://localhost/Chart.js/Chart.js
<html><head>
  <script src="Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
</head></html>

$ curl http://localhost/random/url
<html><head>
  <script src="Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
</head></html>
```

The solution is then to look at `req.url` and serve the correct file:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if (req.url === 'Chart.js/Chart.js') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
        fs.createReadStream('./Chart.js/Chart.js').pipe(res);
        return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(fichier);
    res.end();
});
```

Note that this code snippet isn't a generic solution at all, and will not fit your needs nor will it scale easily to multiple files. You can look at some projects to have a better understanding of the solutions:

- [http-framework](https://github.com/Raynos/http-framework) by Raynos, which is a collection of very simple HTTP servers based only on the `http` module;
- the [static middleware of `connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js)

Comment: Yes as Paul said in the comment I didn't handle the request url. Thank you for helping !